# Object Oriented design example using inheritance in Python Standard Library, e.g. pathlib?

Tags: python, oop

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a typical Object Oriented design in Python Standard Library using inheritance. [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) is another one.

[image: pathlib]

I would like know other example (better involve abstract base class and concrete sub-class) in **Standard Library**.

Comment: Any class in there. You can browse the docs on your own.

Comment: I did but I can't find other except for the 2 examples I listed.

Comment: In Python 3, everything is a class. See, for example, `str`, `list`, `tuple`, etc.

Comment: I mean inheritance

Comment: Do keep in mind that OOP is *not* inheritance. OOP occasionally *uses* inheritance very sparingly, when it makes sense to do so , but OOP is about encapsulating information into objects and limited exposure to data. There's a lot of bad information about what OOP means out there nowadays.

Comment: OK I will make my question be specific.  I know what OO is but I want to know the example of  inheritance.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo please check the updated question.

Comment: @Qiulang are you interested on best OOP practices in python, or somewthing else?

Comment: In this question I am interested in inheritance, especially in standard library.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend two other well-written, well-designed, and easy-to-understand standard library modules that one could study its OOP design (with inheritance, of course).

First one is `logging`. The OOP diagram is shown below:

[image]

`logging` is one of most widely used, pure python, and to be honest, rather simple, standard library modules so it'd be worthwhile to study its design since the module's source code is not that long, and well documented.

Second one is `argparse`.

[image]

Another widely used library module, implemented almost all in pure python, and quite easy to understand. However if you are looking to study its design I still recommend the former one as it is a much shorter module for you to read through.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy  exception is another example.